# Create Maven Uber Jar without dependencies

Tags: java, maven, jar

I'm currently trying to create a library jar from multiple jars that come in one bundle which is out of my control.

I'm stuck at getting rid of the transitive dependencies.

Library pom.xml looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>root-pom</artifactId>
        <groupId>foo</groupId>
        <version>1</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>library</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>out-of-my-control</groupId>
            <artifactId>out-of-my-control</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>shade</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <filters>
                                <filter>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

When I add the library as dependency to one of the projects other modules it works just fine but I still have all the dependencies in the tree as well as packaged into the final product (war, ear).

Is there a better way than excluding the library into another project which is how it was and not wanted anymore or using some local repository which seems a bit hacky to me?

Comment: `I'm stuck at getting rid of the transitive dependencies.` ? Furthermore you are writing about war, ear ? so you are reusing the shaded jar? Usually this is a bad idea...

Comment: I get a bunch of jars which I have to pack into a new Uber jar which than has to be passed to the classpath manually within a ProcessBuilder command. This works - although far from clean code - but now I don't know how to obfuscate the librarys dependencies from the module that use it.

Comment: Using war/ear and classpath manually that sounds very strange. ProcessBuilder you would like to start  via command line.. why obfuscate ?

Comment: Let's not get into the whys as we inherited this project :D The only thing I would like to know is whether it is possible to have a jar with source files minus dependencies generated from multiple jars in one module and only use the newly generated jar as dependency in any other module. So far I had no success achieving this goal.

Comment: Maybe you start explaining us the whys, then we might find a better solution for your problem.